# Google Sheets script for consecutive/nested regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I am trying to reproduce a nested **Regex_MATCH** function on Google Sheets but using a match table (so that I can more easily adapt/edit). It should work with arrays as I will use it with arrayformula.

[Test sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPH_uJBsIKPXulbpRewHN1mIwLG8P-SZr2uSm8ADw2M/edit?usp=sharing)

For instance : I would like to replace a formula like this:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A)>1,If(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "[bB]lue[bB]alloon|Blue_Balloon"),"BlueBalloon_2017",
IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "[hH]ydraphase"),"Hydraphase_2017",
IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "[sS]kinchecker"),"Skinchecker_2017"))),""))
```

With a simple:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A)>1,regexTable(A2:A),"")
```

Where regexTable is a custom function

```
// function loop RE_table named range and get matching value in result_table
function regexTable()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var refs = s.getSheetByName('refs') //get range in refs worksheet
  var RE_table = refs.getRange("D2:D4").getvalues; // list of regular expressions to test
  var result_table = refs.getRange("E2:E4").getvalues; // results to return if REGEX_MATCH = TRUE

  var numRows = RE_table.getNumRows(); // loop through all regular expressions to test
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) { // I would like to exist loop as soon as REGEX_MATCH = TRUE
  if(RE_table[i][1].test())
    return result_table[i][1]         
  }
}
```

This is my first time messing around with google script editor, so my questions are:

1. What is not working?
2. How could this could run as fast as possible?

Thanks a lot, 
Cheers from Switzerland.

Comment: Why not use something like `=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"([A-Z]|[a-z])(\w+)",‌​"$1$2_2017")))`

Comment: because both the input of the regex and the desired result string could be different from what this formula would return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Usage

As custom function from Sheet:

`=getRegexTable(matchArray, regexs, replaces)`

## Function

Paste into script editor:

```
/**
  * returnType  -  "row" or "column" (default)
*/
function getRegexTable(matchArray, regexs, replaces, returnType) {
  // convert attays to lines
  matchArray = convertArrayIntoLine(matchArray);
  matchArray = convertArrayIntoLine(matchArray);
  matchArray = convertArrayIntoLine(matchArray);

  returnType = returnType || "column" // set dafault to rows  
  var machValue = '';
  var result = [];
  // for each machValue
  for (var i = 0, ii = matchArray.length; i < ii; i++)
  {
    machValue = matchArray[i]; 
    result.push(getRegexList(machValue, regexs, replaces));    
  }  
  if (returnType == "column") return convertLineIntoColumn(result);  
  return result;
}

function getRegexList(machValue, regexs, replaces, defaultResult)
{
  var defaultResult = defaultResult || '';
  var regex;
  // for each regex
  for (var i = 0, ii = regexs.length; i < ii; i++)
  {
    if(machValue.match(new RegExp(regexs[i]))) return replaces[i];    
  }  
  return defaultResult;
}

function convertArrayIntoLine(array)
{
  if (!Array.isArray(array[0])) return array;
  var row = [];
  var result = [];
  for (i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++)
  {
    row = array[i];
    for (var j = 0, jj = row.length; j < jj; j++)
    {
      result.push(row[j]);
    }  
  }
  return result;
}

function convertLineIntoColumn(array)
{
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++)
  {
    result.push([array[i]]);  
  }
  return result
}
```

## Tests

I've tested it with this code:

```
function test_getRegexTable()
    {
      var matchArray = [
        'Hydraphase boo',
        'bar Skinchecker',
        'BlueBalloon foo', 
        'BlueBalloon foo', 
        'bar Skinchecker', 
        'boo'];

      var regexs = [
        '[bB]lue[bB]alloon|Blue_Balloon',
        '[hH]ydraphase',
        '[sS]kinchecker'];

        var replaces = [
          'BlueBalloon_2017',
          'Hydraphase_2017',
          'Skinchecker_2017']

      Logger.log(getRegexTable(matchArray, regexs, replaces));
      /* result:
      [
        [Hydraphase_2017], 
        [Skinchecker_2017], 
        [BlueBalloon_2017], 
        [BlueBalloon_2017], 
        [Skinchecker_2017], 
        []]
      */
    }


    function test_convertArrayIntoLine()
    {
      var array = [1, 2, 3];
      Logger.log(convertArrayIntoLine(array));
      array = [[1,2], [3,4]];
      Logger.log(convertArrayIntoLine(array)); 
    }

    function test_convertLineIntoColumn()
    {
      var array = [1, 2, 3];
      Logger.log(convertLineIntoColumn(array));
    }
```

Comment: so cool, but as usual a few questions. Why the triple matchArray = convertArrayIntoLine(matchArray) ? + In getRegexList, the if loop doesn't break if there is a match correct ? Could it be done so that it always returns first match + run time is faster ?

Comment: + it seems to me that you are converting the column array to a line then converting it back to a column array, the sole purpose being for the function to potentially work with horizontal and vertical arrays right ?

Comment: Right, the sole purpose being for the function to potentially work with horizontal and vertical arrays right.  + it's easier to work with arrays as lines.

Comment: + if you add this to your github librabry, please know that the worksheet function requires the column argument =getRegexTable(A2:A, E2:E5, F2:F5,column) works, not =getRegexTable(A2:A, E2:E5, F2:F5)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this formula, please try:

`=ArrayFormula(
VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(--REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(D2:D8),OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)))*
ROW(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A))),,COUNTA(A2:A)),"0 | 0","")*1),{ROW(B:B),B:B},2,))`

range A2:B contains all Regex and Replace strings:

```
[bB]lue[bB]alloon|Blue_Balloon      BlueBalloon_2017
[hH]ydraphase                       Hydraphase_2017
[sS]kinchecker                      Skinchecker_2017
```

cells D2:D4 contains your text:
[image]

---

## Explanation

Dasic idea: `vlookup` row_indexes:
`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(row_indexes,{ROW(B:B),B:B},2,))`

So the problem is to find row_indexes.

1. get matching_results: `REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(D2:D8),OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)))*
   ROW(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A2:A)))` use `traspose` here because the result of matching is 2D-Array.
2. get rid of extra matching_results: `REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(matching_results,,COUNTA(A2:A)),"0 | 0","")*1`
3. use second `tranpose` to convert indexes into row again: ...`VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE`...

This will give incorrect result if some string matches more then 1 regex from list. If so, it's better to wtite script.

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for the answer, but I would need this to work with Arrayformula, this one doesn't work =arrayformula(FILTER($F$2:$F$4,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,$E$2:$E$4))). (in my shared spreadsheet)

Comment: `FILTER` is an ArrayFormula itself. My formula in E2 expands to E3 and E4

Comment: Am i missing something because with D2:D instead of D2:D4 it doesn't work, as the data array size gets different from 3

Comment: You are right. I did not recheck the formula. Please look at my update. Now formula is bigger but it must work as arrayformula. `Filter` won't work here

Comment: Ok thanks it works, could you please expain it ? I am frustrated lol because i don't get why the double transpose

Comment: Ok thanks that's what I thought, I think I have to go through the script anyway

Comment: I like the question and I've written custom function for consecutive/nested regex. The code is long so I posted it in another answer